# vagrant and zeus configuration doesn't work properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, vagrant, zeus

I'm using zeus ruby gem on a vagrant for development
the problem is that running **any of the following commands**

```
zeus start
env ZEUSSOCK=/home/vagrant/zeus.sock zeus start
env ZEUSSOCK=/tmp/zeus.sock zeus start

export ZEUSSOCK=/tmp/zeus.sock
zeus start
```

produces the following error

```
Starting Zeus server
Unable to accept socket connection.
It looks like Zeus is already running. If not, remove .zeus.sock and try again.
```

there is no `.zeus.sock` file created in the project root directory or in any of the specified directories

how can i fix this problem **without using NFS vagrant configuration**

[reference to wiki](https://github.com/burke/zeus/wiki/Using-with-vagrant)

---

running on

Mac osx 10.9

Vagrant 1.3.5

zeus (0.13.3)

Comment: kill the process manually and try starting the zeus again. `ps -ef | grep zeus`. This will give you the process id if running, then kill the process if it exists.

Comment: Killed the Zeus and inotifier  and the ruby processes but didn't work

Comment: is it your production or development environment?

Comment: Although it doesn't matter but it's for the development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution I found was to **update the zeus gem any version grater than 0.13.4.pre2**

any of the upper commands works fine with me on version **0.14.0.rc1** and also on **0.13.4.pre2**

version **0.13.4.pre2** works best with `RAILS_ENV`, as of version **0.14.0.rc1** they suppressed executing test with `RAILS_ENV` enabled